# PHP not work with postgresql?

Tags: php, postgresql, nginx

I already check all 7 similar questions on this site but can't solve the problem

I have:

```
Operating System  CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
WEBserver     nginx version: nginx/1.8.1
PHP           5.4.16 (cli) (built: Nov  6 2016 00:29:02)
psql          (PostgreSQL) 9.4.7
```

But it seems that PostgreSQL support is not enabled in php. My php.info page doesn't show any PostgresSQL section.

```
installed 
Package php-pgsql-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version

uncoment in php.ini  
    extension=php_pgsql.dll 
    extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
```

restarted Nginx

```
I checked /etc/php.ini, and it shows that PostgresSQL is enabled. 

cat /etc/php.ini | grep ^pgsql

pgsql.allow_persistent = On
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = Off
pgsql.max_persistent = -1
pgsql.max_links = -1
pgsql.ignore_notice = 0
pgsql.log_notice = 0

in /etc/php.d 
psql.ini
```

Enabled pgsql extension module
    extension=pgsql.so

How to modify nginx.conf to add Postgres support?

Comment: what is the given error when you command `sudo -u postgres psql`?

Comment: This code return version of psql (9.4.7)

Comment: You should be given a PostgreSQL prompt where you can set up your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you please be more specific. The system administrating  is not is my strong field

Comment: I mean you should be logged into  PostgreSQL prompt and then you can create your database and tables.

Comment: I can login into database. I can create database and tables. I have the problem to add support to PHP.

Comment: Try to run this command `apt-get install php5-pgsql`

Comment: then Uncomment the following in php.ini by removing the ";" `;extension=php_pgsql.so`

Comment: Thank you Aly . I already uncomment extension=php_pgsql.dll  and insttaled Package php-pgsql-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version

Comment: you should uncomment `;extension=php_pgsql.so` not `extension=php_pgsql.dll` since you use `linux`

Comment: I don't have      [ "php_pgsql.so" not found ]

Comment: Try to restart your server.

Comment: service nginx restart,    the same

Comment: try to add `extension=php_pgsql.so` to your php.ini file and restart your server

Comment: I did this to. it's not working. I believe, the problem not in php.ini  bat in  nginx.conf

Comment: Thank you Jay. I need to go now bat will be back on Monday.

Comment: Hi Jay.  I locate the problem. library php_pdo_pgsql.dll,
php_pgsql.dll,  php_pgsql.so not installed in the system. Reinstalling 
 php-pgsql.x86_64 0:5.4.16-42.el7 doen't help.  Any Ideas ? Thank you.

Comment: try this `sudo yum install php-pdo_pgsql`

Comment: Package php-pgsql-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

Comment: open your `php.ini` and search for `php_pdo_pgsql` and  `php_pgsql.so` and remove `;` and restart your server.

Comment: extension=php_pgsql.dll ;   extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll  and php_pgsql.so already aunometed

Comment: the extension `dll` is for window OS, and you use linux so please comment all the extension with `dll` and only uncomment `php_pgsql.so` and `extension=pdo_pgsql.so` and restart your server.